# Optimizing 4 player peer-to-peer network topology

Tags: ios, networking, sprite-kit, multiplayer, gamekit

I'm developing a realtime game using Sprite Kit and Game Kit. The game features a multiplayer mode where 4 players can play with each other. I've been reading the Game Kit programing guide and came across the following passage:

> Although the GKMatch object creates a full peer-to-peer connection
>   between all the participants, **you can reduce the network traffic by
>   layering a ring or client-server networking architecture on top of it**.
>   Figure 8-1 shows three possible network topologies for a four-player
>   game. On the left, a peer-to-peer game has 12 connections between the
>   various devices. However, you could layer a client-server architecture
>   on top of this by nominating one of the devices to act as the host. If
>   your game transmits to or from the host only, you can halve the number
>   of connections. A ring architecture allows devices to forward network
>   packets to the next device only, but further reduces the number of
>   connections. Each topology provides different performance
>   characteristics, so you will want to test different models to find one
>   that provides the performance your game requires.

[image]

So here is where I am confused. Currently in my game I have implemented the peer-to-peer topology, where each user sends their position to every other player in the game. This ends up totaling 12 messages being sent, because each player sends 3 messages.

However according to the documentation, if I layer a client-server topology over my game, I can reduce the network traffic by reducing the number of connections. If I do this though, then each client will send their position to the host and then the host would need to relay those positions to the remaining clients. So now one player (the host) needs to work extra because the clients no longer communicate with each other. And then we still end up with 12 messages. The host sends 9 messages (3 messages for each player, plus 6 messages for relaying the other clients' positions) then each client sends 1 position message to the host. 9 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 12 messages. Which makes sense, all we did was unevenly distribute the message sending, so now one player needs to work harder to makeup for the less work the other players are doing.

Furthermore, relaying the client messages takes additional time because each client's position now needs to pass through the host.

So while there are now less connections, one player is sending more messages (9 messages) rather than each player evenly distributing the workload (i.e. each player sending 3 messages). This seems like it would lead to a greater chance for disconnects to occur because it will be easier for the host to disconnect from the match.

So can someone explain to me how network traffic gets reduced by layering a client-server topology? Does just the fact of having less connections in the match reduce network traffic even though overall messages are the same? Keep in mind, there is no dedicated server here, I (and the documentation) am talking about layering a client-server topology on top of the peer-to-peer match. Also isn't the host at a greater chance of disconnecting because he is sending 3X as much messages as the other players. After all, the GKMatch will disconnect a player after a brief period of packet loss. Or does simply the fact of having 12 connections have a greater chance for disconnects because of the supposedly increased traffic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry for the very short answer to a very descriptive and well written question, but the answer is simple. The Server (you used the term "host", but this is confusing) does not have to send 3 separate messages to each client. The Server collects all the information and sends just one message containing all information to each client.

Comment: 2 Questions: 1) Won't the single message just become larger. Is this better then sending a series of smaller packets? 2) What about for action messages. I.e. the player does something like shoots or heals etc.. I can't really collect for something like this. Maybe quote this and respond in your answer if you don't have enough room.

Comment: 1) In most cases, yes it is better. Think about the overhead involved in sending each message. 2) Sorry, I don't see why not?

Comment: Position is sent every x seconds, so I can simply have the server send a single message of all positions to each client. But actions can come in at any time, there is no interval. And there are many different types of actions. I suppose the server could "listen" and collect actions that each player sent and then send one combined packet to each client. But the window of listening would have to be so small to prevent lag, that no collection could possibly take place unless 2 players sent an action at the same time. Unless you can think of a better solution to this? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, please think about this scenario. Assuming no bandwidth problems, if the latency between players A, B and C were all 20ms, but the latency between D and other players were 200ms, how would you deal with this in the Peer-to-Peer topology? What I am getting at is that the problem you have described is actually a generic problem that exists in ALL network programming regardless of the topology used.

Comment: What I was getting at is that not all messages can be combined like position. I see now that position messages can defiantly benefit from client-server with no consequences. But my action type messages unfortunately won't.

Comment: Let's look just at position packets though. If I do what you say and send a single packet to each user. The this means each client will send and receive 1 message per x seconds.  And the host will send and receive 3 packets per x seconds (the packets will be slightly larger but it's negligible). Does this mean that relative to the host, there is no benefit? Or does the host benefit because other users are sending/receiving less messages? I'm not sure exactly how Apple handles the GKMatch. I think data is sent to Game Center servers then relayed to user devices.

Comment: Sorry, I think you missed my point. The reason you think position messages can be combined is because each player sends the position at regular intervals to the server. If, however, a position message from one player arrives late, what happens? What I was trying to get at was that even with your other action messages, you may still have to put them in regular time slots. If no action taken, send a null action message. If you send network messages on an as-needed basis, you have no safeguard against actions arriving out of order.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to get at is, I want to minimize disconnections from the match. It's obvious that clients will defiantly benefit from client-server topology. But it looks like host will still be sending and receiving same number of messages so he will still have same chance of disconnecting as before. Or does the host benefit simply because the GKMatch has to handle less network traffic overall, or is it incorrect to think this way. Thanks again for taking your time to respond.

Comment: In Server/Client topology, the server will always do more work compared to any single player in the Peer-to-Peer topology, both in terms of networking and general processing. This does not necessarily mean that the chance of disconnection is higher because you can choose which player will act as the Server, taking into account important metrics such as latency. I think we should stop because extended discussions in comments are frowned upon.